# Will I be able to implement a modern design?

Tags: branding, design, sp-online

I have been assigned by my team to create a list of solutions to build a site, among other solutions one was SharePoint. I was given a design sketch similar to this [baccarat online](https://betandslots.com/guides/baccarat-online/) guide. I am wondering if it's possible using SharePoint to build a site that has a similar modern design and if I will be able to include shortcodes and tables.

I really like the platform and the idea behind it, and all the benefits of collaboration, but I am not sure if it's the perfect solution.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely build very similar portal in SharePoint online, please check this site for design options https://spdesign.azurewebsites.net/ . You can check the [SharePoint Lookback](https://lookbook.microsoft.com/) site for design examples. I am sure you will be amazed by the things you can do using out of the box web parts available for modern design.

In my opinion, you can achieve most of the tasks using SharePoint out of the box webparts only, but, if you require something custom then [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) can be the option to go.

There can be some limitations on the styling that you can use but the default modern style for SharePoint is already excellent.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint you can develop any website, you can convert any html design to SharePoint master page. But note that mostly sharedpoint is used a document management system inside organization or as public portal. Due to its options to configure permissions and workflow automation. If you need to deal with high number or data and users, SharePoint may not be a good options. As its a powerful system, it has some performance issue also.